# A mess happens when i try to unwrap my model, any idea whats causing this?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

[image: here is the mess of the unwrapping :(]

Please help i have been at this for a couple of hours, and i have no idea how to fix this. 
[image]

Comment: Can you add the blend file? I think you need to add more seams in problematic areas.

Comment: have you removed any doubles (in edit mode W --> remove doubles). And a blendfile would help.

Comment: i have removed the doubles, and ill add the file now :)

Comment: add the top of your sword are a lot of vertices that aren 't connected to each other. So you have to fix that. Also the normals have to be recalculated and in some cases be flipped. And you need extra seams around all the bulges of the sword.

Comment: what are the normals ? and how do i do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is your model. You have got a lot of strange faces in the inside of your sword, and on top of the sword some vertices that are not connected while they should be. So you have to delete all the inner faces and connect the vertices that should be connected. And then add the seams and UV-unwrap the model 
In the blendfile I add, I corrected it all so you can see the difference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, your advice will help a lot in the future. Also thank you for doing it <3